# join twice on the same table rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to join on the same table twice to get username and username_to

```
@array = UsersWalletsBalancesFrozen.
joins("INNER JOIN userds userdsidto ON transactions.user_id_to=userdsidto.id").
joins("INNER JOIN userds userdsid   ON transactions.user_id = userdsid.id").select("*")
```

This get me the last join only works i think it's overrides is there any solution to that

Comment: Can you check if your data is not missing matching rows?. Also, I would prefer to use a left outer join in this query because if no matching rows exist for first join it will not have any rows to match with the second join

Answer (score 0):

Just as a quick solution... Have you tried to put it in the same method call:

```
@array = UsersWalletsBalancesFrozen.joins("INNER JOIN userds AS user_to userdsidto ON transactions.user_id_to=user_to.id INNER JOIN userds userdsid AS user_from   ON transactions.user_id = user_from.id").select("transactions.*, user_to.username, user_from.username")
```

?

PS: `select('*')` will be called by default. No need to explicitly specify it.

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: Can you paste your `UsersWalletsBalancesFrozen` code to the question?

Comment: What fields do you need to be loaded from user? (I doubt you will use all of them)

Comment: i have a transfer from a user to another user so the table of UsersWalletsBalancesFrozen  include userid and user_id_to i need to show the username of both user and user_to username

Comment: Why am I asking about your model.... why you don't go with associations? Like `UsersWalletsBalancesFrozen.joins(:association1, :association2).select(...)`